# How to get latest "Activation count" for license from license4j API

Tags: license4j

I have enabled activation and deactivation feature enabled for License Type = "License Text"

I need the information how many latest activation count are pending, there might be some license deactivated.
I have search API provided by license4j but wont find any exposed API.
Able to get License Quantity but for current activation count not able to see any API.

Is any way to get this information ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an own ALGAS? I just take such information out of its underlying database directly if needed. Sorry not being able to help you if using Online.License4J since I'm not aware of such an API function, too.

By the way: License4J team don't answer my questions for weeks now, and you didn't get answer, too, it looks like. Looks like they are unavailable due to unknown reasons. Also, my recently expired ALGAS license has not been renewed to date despite timely payment, which puts me in a bad situation. :-(

I like License4J for its simplicity but that's not that funny actually.